# Why won't SASM build my hello.asm file in Arch Linux 64 using NASM assembler and gcc linker?

Tags: build, sasm

My system is Arch linux 64, my file is just a hello.asm
The setting for SASM is as follows:

```
Mode: x64
Assembler : NASM
Assemble optionss : -g -f elf64 $SOURCE$ -l $LSTOUTPUT$ -o $PROGRAM.OBJ$
Linking options : $PROGRAM.OBJ$ $MACRO.OBJ$ -g -o $PROGRAM$  -no-pie
Assembler path : nasm
Linker path : gcc
Object file name : program.o
```

The build gives following:

```
[13:18:59] Warning! Errors have occurred in the build:
/tmp/SASM/program.asm:6: error: expression syntax error
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /tmp/SASM/program.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[13:18:59] Before debugging you need to build the program.
```

The build is supposed to build hello.asm instead of program.asm

Reinstall SASM from the package or build SASM directly from the source won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the -g from the assembler options.
I am not sure why but I had the experience that some versions of SASM cannot handle the debugging-information.

About the occurrence of "program.asm":
SASM uses a tmp-directory for building files.
Program.asm is just the naming of the placeholder for SASM and therefore correct.

The whole other config on sasm-side looks good, please provide the code if that did not help.